# Is there mail server/client software that has a user experience like Gmail?

Tags: email, email-server, gmail

My company is stuck with an old imap/pop mail server that is accessed from Outlook. Everybody uses Gmail as a personal email and loves it more than the one used at work. Is there a combination of mail server and client that will give me an user experience like the one from email?

It doesn't have to be free software. Would be nice if the server works in Linux.

Comment: Guess its just a matter of taste and what you're used to - I was on the gmail beta early but loathed the gmail 'user experience' to the point I deleted my account last year. And I haven't missed it.

It might help to define what exactly you mean you want when you say you want a 'user experience like Gmail". Do you just want a slick web based UI, do you want an actual gmail clone? Are there one or two features you consider 'must have' but otherwise wouldn't notice or care about the rest of it if it was reasonable?

Answer (score 4):

It is for this reason that many places are switching to Google Apps, effectively outsourcing their email to Gmail directly. It really makes sense for small offices, assuming the legal issues are satisfied.

Comment: Agreed.  Nothing like letting someone else handle the backup and DR issues.

Answer (score 3):

[Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/downloads/os-downloads.html) [cloned the interface](http://blog.zimbra.com/blog/archives/2007/06/we-call-it-zmail.html) and never released it publically, but what they *did* release for Zimbra 5 looks fairly similar:

[image: Zmail]

I'm not sure what it looks like in the current version.

Comment: Another Vote for Zimbra, the latest one is fantastic. Website has screenshots. Zimbra also supports secure pop, imap, webmail, mobile, etc

Answer (score 1):

I personally love the new outlook 2010 / exhcange 2010 experience - acutally a lot more than gmail.

Comment: The OWA interface is a massive improvement, too (and you get that web-based love) - assuming you're using IE, of course.

Comment: @Kara - I thought I read that OWA Premium no longer was going to require IE in Exchange 2010. Did this change? :(

Comment: It's not *required* but it's sub-optimal (from an '07 perspective, but I somehow doubt MS will ever strive for a full Chrome featurelist).

Comment: They actually do - and I look forward to theuir hopefully soon coming use of silverlight in the OWA client. Personally for me it is good enough now to regularly use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several open source web mail frontends: Horde, Squirrel Mail, Roundcube. They will work with a variety of backend setups.